# LG Smart TV Youtube Player doesn't work

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, swfobject, samsung-smart-tv, lg

I try to run youtube player in my javascript application for smart tv.

I took the code from official youtube api docs and inserted it in the page.
It's a very simple code.

```
<div id="ytapiplayer">no flash?</div>

window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function() {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.loadVideoById('EDwb9jOVRtU', 0, 'medium');
}

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1", 
                   "ytapiplayer", "640", "360", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V5s9W/

When I run it in browser — everything works fine. In emulator I have the same result. On samsung TV and samsung emulator — the same.

But when I create a drm zip with web hosted app and insert usb in real LG Smart TV - it doesn't work!
Does anybody know what happened?

Comment: What model and year is your TV? Many of the slightly older ones have very limited support for Flash video.

Comment: Have you tried opening this page in TV Browser?

Comment: yes, sure. I knew that all new version of LG doesn't support flash. So I start to use html5 player youtube. thanks for answers!